# How to undo Mistakenly post flagged?

Tags: support, flagging

I have flagged a post by mistake. is there any way to not count that post as flagged or i can do like something "un-flag" ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot un-flag a post; you need to wait moderators handle that flag, and then you are able to raise another flag for the same post.